# value of salt changing on storing value in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, passwords, salt

I'm using the code below to create salt in PHP.

```
$length=100;
$bool=true;
$salt=openssl_random_pseudo_bytes ( $length, $bool );
```

when I echo the value it display this value (one instance)

```
×YOEú ßPŽžJZýr³€žYM½N±~ÄŽ¼D‚ÝÆFÕ`O$I$îÇF    üKøäƒþ¥_5ûù„Ð… Ïq®ùä. ³æ¤ljî¬}Të‚´ù­B#3U96
```

but on storing in the database it gets changed to

```
Ñx€gþ‚Î€³€Œ¯´N§Å·.:gºÈá•ïjÇÖ…áf6uIùYbx}û€·iÀ0èFšDö¼6¥qzMéÁi‡±
```

The field is using latin1_swedish_ci encoding.

[signup script](http://pastebin.com/ZPan1cgk)

[script containing hashing function, salt generator](http://pastebin.com/54dVGDiR)

[table structure](http://s15.postimg.org/dzztf7lqj/Untitled.png)

Comment: is the field type varchar ?

Comment: Yes, I've even added a link to image displaying table structure.

Comment: ok, try change the type to blob

Comment: Nope still different.
Does encoding type have any problem. Would changing encoding to utf8 help?

Comment: i don't think so, but if you want to store the salt in db, then select it, you can store it base64 encoded

Comment: I mean if you'll manipulate with your salt in php

Comment: I tried once again changing to blob worked as well as changing the encoding type.

Comment: great! thank you for valuable question and solution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` returns a raw byte stream, as the name suggests. It doesn't return "characters" which are intended to be readable. How those bytes are being displayed as characters depends entirely on the interpreting party; here quite apparently MySQL is interpreting the bytes in a different encoding than the browser/console where you're displaying it from PHP.

If you're storing those bytes in MySQL, you should be storing them in a BLOB type column, because they're a meaningless blob.

If you want to treat them as characters, you need to encode them. The best is probably a simple `bin2hex($salt)`, which encodes the binary data to hex. Alternatively use `base64_encode`.

Secondarily, the second parameter to `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` is not supposed to be passed as a boolean. It's a pass-by-reference variable which allows you to check after the fact whether the bytes were generated with strong security:

```
$salt = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($length, $strong);
if ($strong) {
    // $salt is strong
} else {
    // $salt is weak
}
```